# ways of putting letters into envelope

Tags: combinatorics

Number of ways of putting four different letters in correspondingly five addressed envelopes so that no letter is put in correct envelope.

i have no idea to do this

thanks

Comment: You have **four** letters but **five** envelopes. Are you sure?

Comment: Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ represent the events that the first, second, etc... letters respectively *are* put in the correct envelope.  We have then $A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots$ represents the set of outcomes which violate your desired condition.  Can you calculate $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots|$?  What do you know about inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: @JMoravitz thats gonna hell of complicated

Comment: @J.Deff not complicated at all in my opinion... The theory behind my hint is exactly the same as that of the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Total cases$=5\times 4 \times 3 \times 2 = 120$

At least one goes to correct envelope$={4 \choose 1}\times 4 \times 3 \times 2 = 96$

But there is a problem, we double counted few cases (more than one correct cases)$={4 \choose 2} \times 3 \times 2 = 36$

Again there is a problem, we double counted few cases (more than two correct cases)$={4 \choose 3} \times 2 = 8$

Finally, we double counted the all the correct case$={4 \choose 4} = 1$

Answer is $=120-96+36-8+1=53$.

Comment: can you elaborate everything.