# Permute numbers from 1 to n so that every number is in a different position

Tags: combinatorics

I want to permutate numbers from 1 to n in a way that for all i=1 to n, i is not in the i-th position.

Example:

5 4 2 1 3 is accepted because 5 is in the 1st position, 4 is in the 2nd position and so on...

1 3 2 5 4 is not accepted because 1 is in the 1st position

In how many way can i do this? I tried combinatorics but it seems to be a bit complicated. Is there simple formula for this?

Comment: Use principle of inclusion-exclusion. I think it has been answered many times before (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269463/ways-of-putting-letters-into-envelope))

Comment: The term for it is [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)  There are many questions on the site.  There are the closest natural to $\frac {n!}e$ of them

Comment: oh, so do I delete this? it's going to be closed soon so...

Comment: It is often hard to find a known solution if you don't know the name for it, like here.  Once you know the name, you can search for it and find much information.